# ¿Por qué mi subconsulta me vota más de un resultado dentro del WHILE pero solo una fuera? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda extraña, no logro resolverla. Tengo un bucle WHILE:

```sql
DECLARE @i INT = 1
    DECLARE @end INT
    SET @end = (SELECT MAX(indiceCliente) FROM [@resultadoTabla(OK)] ) 

DECLARE @tablaFinal TABLE(cliente VARCHAR(255), emision VARCHAR(255), 
total NUMERIC(12,2))
    DECLARE @clienteFinal VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE @emisionFinal VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE @totalFinal NUMERIC(12,2)
    
    WHILE @i <= @end BEGIN

            SET @clienteFinal = (SELECT DISTINCT cliente 
FROM [@resultadoTabla(OK)] 
WHERE indiceCliente = @i)
            
            SET @emisionFinal = (SELECT emision 
FROM [@resultadoTabla(OK)] 
WHERE saldo_a_restar>=0 AND indiceCliente = @i 
ORDER BY emision ASC OFFSET  0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)

            SET @totalFinal = (SELECT SUM(IoE) 
FROM [@resultadoTabla(OK)] 
WHERE saldo_a_restar >= 0 AND indiceCliente = @i)

            
            INSERT INTO @tablaFinal(cliente, emision, total)
            VALUES (@clienteFinal, @emisionFinal, @totalFinal)

            SET @i = @i+1 
    END
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente: `Mens. 512, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 12 La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.`

Basándome en la línea del error sería la del `SET @clienteFInal`; de tal modo lo compruebo sacándolo fuera del `WHILE` y no me bota ningún error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cliente FROM [@resultadoTabla(OK)] WHERE indiceCliente = 1
```

El output:

[image: Resultado Query]

Espero puedan apoyarme. Gracias.

Comment: Exactamente, estas dentro de un while.. te fijates con todos los otros valores de i????

Comment: Como podría con una consulta SQL? Pasa que son más de 100K registros. Justamente se me acaba de ocurrir que puede ser que un `cliente` esté tomando el mismo `ID` de otro y en ese caso habría dos `cliente` con el mismo ID, ahí es donde me está trayendo dos resultados (o más).

Comment: Hazle debug y revisa usando mensajes, a ver en qué registro falla.

Comment: Una consulta, para poder ordenar los ID usé el `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 1)` donde los 1 hacen referencia al campo que usé. ¿Es posible que haciendo uso de ello pueda devolver un mismo ID para dos campos cliente diferentes? Cabe destacar que para el `PARTITION BY` usé un campo y para `ORDER BY` usé otro distinto.

Comment: Y si haces un log y te fijas que Id falla? digo no..

Comment: Ok, ya lo hice. Efectivamente me trae el mismo `ID` para dos personas diferentes. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar ello? Si el `ID` lo generé usando el  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 1`